# I am confused about the sum indices of these posterior distribution formulas

Tags: distributions, inference, variational-bayes, bayesian-optimization

I am reading this [notes](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Ehanxiaol/slides/hanxiaol-bvmf.pdf) and trying to understand how the posterior distribution formulas of the variational variables involved have been calculated. I am confused about the indices of the summation. Could anyone help?.

we have the following optimal expression for the variational posterior distribution
$$\log q^*(\theta_i) =  \mathbb{E}_{q(\theta_{-i})}[\log p(X, Z |\theta)] + const$$

where $\theta_{-i}$ means the set of unobserved variables except the current variable $\theta_i$, $\mathbb{E}$ is the expectation, and $\theta = \{\pi, Z, \mu_k, \kappa_k\}$ is a set of unobserved variable with the corresponding prior distributions:

[image]

The idea is to calculate the closed-form solution of each variational variable.

In slide #7:

[image]

here $z_{ik}, \pi_k, \kappa_k, \mu_k$ are random variables and $x_i$ not.

My question is: Why the sum $\sum^{N}_{i=1}$ was ignored from the formula?

To my understanding, the variational variable $\log{q^*(z_i)}$ depends only on the current random variable $z_{ik}$.

In slide #8:

[image]

$\setminus z_i$ means the set of unobserved variables except the current variable $z_i$

The question here is: why do we consider only the $k^{th}$ vector, and we neglect the sum $\sum^{K}_{j\neq k}$.

To my understanding, the variational variable $\mu$ is updated vector-wise, and $\mu_k$ depends only on the $k^{th}$ vector, so we don't consider the remaining $\sum^{N}_{j\neq k}$.

Are my interpretations correct? any help is appreciated

Comment: As it's not immediately obvious, please may you clarify the nature of the variational distributions $q^{\setminus z_i}$ and $q^{\setminus \boldsymbol{\mu}_k}$?

Comment: Thank you @microhaus, I updated the description, I have also put the link of the document for full details.

Comment: +1 for adding relevant details, it clarifies your question. However, it still does not clarify exactly what $q^{\setminus z_i}$ and $q^{\setminus \boldsymbol{\mu}_k}$ refer to in $\mathbb{E}_{q^{\setminus z_i}}[\cdot]$ and $\mathbb{E}_{q^{\setminus \boldsymbol{\mu}_k}}[\cdot]$. Do you have any other information on what this might mean? I have a strong suspicion I know what this is referring, but would appreciate absolute clarity before writing an answer.

Comment: @microhaus $\setminus \mu_k$ means $\theta - \mu$, the set of unobserved variables except the current variable $\mu$

Comment: @microhaus I added the requested details, hope it is clear now

Comment: Thank you for adding details. I’m familiar with variational inference and am confident that I can assist. But because the way I’m used to solving these kinds of problems differs slightly to the way your instructor has used, I will need some time to reconcile my understanding. Will aim to get back to you by end of the week at the latest.